# show sign_in page in root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

In a rails 3 project with devise, how puts the login page /users/sign_in in the root path.

I try in `routes.rb`puts  `root :to => "users#sign_in"` or `root :to => "sessions#sign_in"`, but dont works, or other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your `routes.rb` with :

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
```